# Hide div A if div B is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to hide div A when Div B has no content inside, I have tried multiple strings of code but I think I am completely missing the idea, here is what I have currently tried

```
if( $('#b').is(':empty') ) {
$('#a').hide;
}
```

Comment: Well, what you have there is a property and not a method call... you can't really expect it to *do* anything when you're not calling a method.

Comment: @BoltClock so for instance if I add this to an onlick function it might actually fire?, because its not fire at all?

Comment: No, hide is a method, but you're calling it like a property instead of what it really is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
if( $('#b').text()=='' ) {
$('#a').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ='a'>asdasdasd</div>
<div id='b'></div>
```

Comment: Well this works perfectly thank you kinds sir!, can you maybe explain why mine is not working?

Comment: `hide` is a method, but you're calling it like a property instead of what it really is..So with methods you need to append `()` at the end

Comment: Ok Ok I fully understand now! thank you @Tushar Gupta!